# Mysql errores de compilación después de cambiar el nombre de un campo

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Resulta que después de cambiar en una tabla el nombre de un campo, pues tenía varios trigger que seguían usando el nombre del campo old.

Y sólo me enteré de estos errores cuando instalé la BD en otro ordenador la BD, tras ejecutar el script del dump que hice anteriormente en el ordenador original.

Esoy acostumbrado a que en oracle (mediante la aplicación plsql) pues pueda comprobar cuales son sus errores de compilación (una de sus opciones que consulto habitualmente).

¿Existe alguna manera en mysql de comprobar si después de un cambio en la tabla, pues tuviera algún error de compilación?

Uso HeidiSQL, por si esto sirviera y esta aplicación tuviera esta opción.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Independientemente del DBMS que utilices al ejecutar las querys para crear la base de datos, suele indicar los errores que se producen. En función de las configuraciones, se puede indicar que se interrumpa el volcado o se ignore si hay errores, pero en cualquier caso se indican. También puedes revisar el Log de mysql.

Comment: Creo que no lo he explicado bien y necesito ayuda por favor. La idea es que tengo varias tablas creadas a, b y c . Ahora tengo un trigger de cada una de las tablas, pero 15 días después modifico el nombre de un campo de la tabla a. Pero el trigguer de la tabla a no le cambio el nombre del campo (y lo usé). Que ocurre?. Que mysql no me avisa o no se como ver el aviso de que el trigguer tiene un campo mal porque ya no se llama así. Oracle, bajo plsql (DBMS) tiene una opción que comprueba los fallos en todos los sitios y por eso quería saber si lo tiene también mysql. Gracias de antemano